# Validate cookie matches a list of hard-coded values

Tags: php, cookies, xss

[As per a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24488101/php-theme-switcher-using-a-cookie/24488297#24488297) I've got a basic script which re-themes my site by updating the CSS used, but does so in an insecure way that echo's a value that's open to an XSS attack:

**index.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Theme Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo (!isset($_COOKIE['style'])?'normal':$_COOKIE['style']) ?>.css" />
  </head>

  <body>

    <form action="changestyle.php" method="post">
      <select name="choice">
        <option value="classic" selected>Classic View</option>
        <option value="holiday">Holiday View</option>
        <option value="normal">Normal View</option>
      </select>
     <input type="submit" value="Go">
   </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

**changestyle.php**

```
<?php
  $year = 31536000 + time();
  setcookie('style', $_POST['choice'], $year);
  header('Location: index.php');
  exit();
?>
```

I've been advised that the best way to circumvent such an attack is to perform a check in `index.php` to verify the cookie matches a list of hard-coded values.

I'm assuming to do this I need to update the existing php statement:

```
<?php echo (!isset($_COOKIE['style'])?'normal':$_COOKIE['style']) ?>
```

To something like:

```
$required = array('classic', 'holiday', 'normal');

if(!isset($_COOKIE['style'])) {
    echo 'normal';
} else {
    // If cookie 'style' matches $required perform echo.
}
```

No idea how to write this statement correctly though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the user-inputed cookie value is equal to one of your hard-coded values, so just make sure it's in your array:

```
$required = array('classic', 'holiday', 'normal');
$style_name = 'normal';
if(!empty($_COOKIE['style']) && in_array( $_COOKIE['style'] , $required ))
  $style_name = $_COOKIE['style'];
```

Now the `$style_name` variable contains a validated stylesheet name which you can use in your link tag echo statement.

Comment: Thanks oliakaoil, thats spot on.